# user activity log Joomla, Wordpress or Drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, content-management-system

I will be building a site which will be running on a content management system - Joomla, Wordpress or Drupal. Of course I am not closed to any other suggestions if you are using another CMS which you like.

One condition is a user activity plugin, module or component. It will be closed site for registered users only and my client wants to see what are the users viewing.

Do you know about any module, plugin, component which would allow me to track users' activities on the site? Especially what pages they have seen and which they did not. I would prefer a free plugin which could be further altered to suit my needs.

Thank you for your answers!
V.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [MODx](http://www.modx.com), there you can easily drop in tracking codes. Or write your own trackers in PHP. As far as i know does MODx also offer some kind of tracking itself, but I am not sure. One of the advantages of MODx is, that you have clean separation of HTML and PHP, which most CMS do not offer, while having a lot of flexibility in your design. When you start I recommend working with Evolution. Revolution might be a little overwhelming for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with all 3 of the CMS's you mention, I'd suggest the latest version of [Joomla](http://demo.joomla.org/).  There is a large collection of statistical plugins available from their [extensions repositiory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics).  While there is plenty of debate about the use of a CMS to begin with, they take 80% of the develoment out of the equation, leaving your time to develop your business solution, and Joomla seems to have the largest collection of newly developed code.

Comment: yeah, i would like to go with joomla because i have worked with it in the past, but while checking the extensions they are not that up to date and most of them does not offer user tracking capabilities .. i doubt i could programm something myself

Comment: I can't speak to the others but Joomla is very easy to customize and extend with your own custom extensions. The CMS is pretty good but the underlying framework is its real strength.

Comment: Dunno...j4Age nearly tells me what the color of their underwear was when they visited each page...

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress [UserTracker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/usertracker/) plugin, or [Statistics](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) Drupal module should suit your needs. I'm not familiar with Joomla, so I can't give you a recommendation there.

Protip: If you are asking which CMS to use in a general sense, you will start a flame war, I promise. I think it's best to research each one independently and decide which you think you'll be most comfortable using.

Answer (score 0):

j4Age is great, it tracks user, page, time, IP, browser, etc.
The only thing I dislike: page_id has its own classification, different from Joomla's core.